# Comparing mysql timestamps

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to compare timestamps by finding out if particular timestamp field is greater than 15 days ago.

So if I try this on my database, I get:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) // 2012-04-08 11:00:54
```

The field concerned has a value: `2012-04-20 21:18:14`.

So when I try:

```
SELECT * FROM (`payments`) WHERE `LastUpdated` >= 'DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)'
```

I get no rows returned? Am I comparing dates incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are treating the DATE_SUB function as a string.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM (`payments`) WHERE `LastUpdated` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)
```

Comment: Damn it, I was using my active record in Codeigniter incorrectly!